# TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable - python

Tags: python, list, int, typeerror

I'm trying to make a small program that gets a random website and counts the elements.

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "elements counter.py", line 23, in <module>
    if elem[1] == string:
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

Here is my code:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError

print 'Fetching URL..'

try:
    html = urlopen(Request("http://www.randomwebsite.com/cgi-bin/random.pl"))
except URLError:
    html = urlopen(Request("http://www.randomwebsitemachine.com/random_website/"))

print 'Loading HTML..'

ellist = [(None,None),]
isel = False
string = ''

for char in html.read():
    if char == '<':
        isel=True
    elif isel:
        if char == ' ' or char == '>':
            if string in ellist:
                for elem in ellist:
                    if elem[1] == string:
                        elem[0] += 1
            else:
                ellist += (1,string)
            isel = False
            string = ''
        else:
            string += char

print sorted(ellist, key = lambda tempvar: tempvar[0])

html.close()
raw_input()
```

Please point out if you find anything more wrong in the code.

Comment: you should not name your variable `string`, it may clash with `string` module

Comment: @AnuragUniyal It's common practice to use module names as identifiers, so long as you're not using that module in your program. There are just too many to worry about it. The convention is to avoid using commonly used built-ins as identifiers, like `list` or `dict`. Lesser used ones like `file` or `id` depend on who you ask -- they're commonly used in the standard library.

Comment: @agf yes but it is usually better to avoid names which clash with std lib modules or are not descriptive enough, string would be better named as what is is supposed to be e.g. search_str, or tag_name etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
            ellist += (1,string)
```

it's the same as

```
            ellist.extend((1,string))
```

so `ellist` looks something like

```
[(None, None), 1, string]
```

so when you get to the second element in the `for` loop, it's an `int` not a `tuple`.

Instead, do

```
            ellist.append((1,string))
```

or, if you really want to use `+=`,

```
            ellist += [(1,string)]
```

The rest of your code looks basically right, but note you won't properly handle angle brackets in quotes or in HTML comments. If you want to parse HTML, use one of the many HTML parsers out there, like Python's HTMLParser module, lxml, or BeautifulSoup.